# How to drop pairs in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to drop value pairs in a dictionary if the first element contains a certain string (time or session), but keep the remaining pairs (word and group). `dic1` is the one I have and `dic2` is the one I would like.

I have written a one liner that removes the *entire* value element but thats not really what I want...I wonder where I am going wrong.

```
dic1 = dict({'a':[{'word': '3', 'group': 'a', 'time': 'nat'},
                  {'word': '1', 'group': 'b', 'session':'199'},
                  {'word': '0', 'group': 'c'}]})

dic2 = dict({'a':[{'word': '3', 'group': 'a'},
                  {'word': '1', 'group': 'b'},
                  {'word': '0', 'group': 'c'}]})

{k :[x for x in dic1[k] if (x.keys()) == {'word', 'group'}] for k, in dic1}
```

Comment: if a one line is too obscure try a normal loop where you can debug line by line and see why it doesn't do what you expect.. You will then see that there's something wrong using the `==` operator like you do.

Comment: Note that `x.keys()` will return [`dictionary view object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) and it will never be equal to a `set`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unwanted keys are inside `x` here:

```
{k :[x for x in dic1[k] if (x.keys()) == {'word', 'group'}] for k, in dic1}
```

You need one more dict comprehension inside your comprehension:

```
out = {k: [{k2:v2 for k2,v2 in x.items() if k2 not in ('time', 'session')} for x in v1] for k, v1 in dic1.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'a': [{'word': '3', 'group': 'a'},
  {'word': '1', 'group': 'b'},
  {'word': '0', 'group': 'c'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code which only keeps needed fields:

```
    dic2 = {k :[{'word':x['word'], 'group' : x['group']} for x in dic1[k]] for k, in dic1}
```